# Dagger is not generating DaggerAppComponent class for AppComponent

Tags: android, android-studio, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

My "BaseServiceModule" is:

```
@Module
public class BaseServiceModule {

private static final int TIMEOUT = 40;
private static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 40;
private static final int WRITE_TIMEOUT = 40;

private String url = ServerData.getInstance().getServerUrl();


@Provides
String provideURL(){
    return url;
}

@Provides
Gson provideGson(){
    return new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
}

// Get BASE URL.
@Provides
public  Retrofit.Builder provideRetrofitBuilder(OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
       return new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ServerData.getInstance().getServerUrl()).client(okHttpClient);
}


// for custom URL, GSON
@Provides
public  Retrofit getCustomUrlInstance_Gson(Retrofit.Builder retrofitBuilder) {
    return retrofitBuilder.build();
}


@Provides
public  Retrofit.Builder getBuilderGson(Retrofit.Builder builder, GsonConverterFactory gsonConverterFactory) {
    return builder.addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory);
}

// GSON Converter Factory
@Provides
public GsonConverterFactory provideGsonConverterFactory( Gson gson){
    return GsonConverterFactory.create(gson);
}


@Provides
public OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient() {
    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(WRITE_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
}

}
```

My ServiceModule is:

```
@Module
public class ServiceModule {

  @Provides
  GlobalApiInterface provideGlobalApiInterfaceGson(Retrofit retrofit){
     return retrofit.create(GlobalApiInterface.class);
 }
}
```

My ActivityComponent is:

```
@Component(dependencies = AppComponent.class, modules = ServiceModule.class)
public interface ActivityComponent {
    void inject(SchoolCodeActivity schoolCodeActivity);
}
```

My AppComponent is:

```
@Component(modules = BaseServiceModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
  Retrofit getRetrofitInstance();
  Retrofit.Builder getRetrofitBuilder();
 }
```

My Application class is:

```
 public class MainApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
     AppComponent component = // not making "DaggerAppComponent" final class

  }   
}
```

Dagger version using:

```
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.24"
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.16'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.16'
```

I gone through the other DUPLICATE questions for solution but couldn't find the relevent solution.
I am a new starter on Dagger and i am trying to make instance of Retrofit at Application level and interface related to Retrofit at Activity Level. 'GlobalApiInterface' is an interface for retrofit and 'ServiceModule' is the module that setting interface in retrofit.

Please help me in resolving where i committed mistake.

Comment: Are there any error messages in the `Build` window?

Comment: @BartekLipinski- No, infact i am able to create "DaggerActivityComponent".

Answer (score 0):

You need to **build and run** the project at least once after implementing dagger. It will automatically generate **DaggerAppComponent** class

Can you please try with this dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.25.3'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.25.3'
```

after gradle sync successful invalidate cache & restart. Then Run your project.

Comment: No, not working.  Is there any possibility that dagger couldn't create class for those components which are not used anywhere?

Comment: i think you should go with Scoping too. That may resolve your problem.

Comment: @MrCode - both of yours answer were right. Mainly,  I am missing Scoping thats why DaggerAppComponent was not generating.